# IOS 12.1.4 - Apps bugged, can't delete or reinstall

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, ios-appstore

I recently changed to a temporary iPhone 6, while my main iPhone is being repaired. Because this phone has a lot less RAM, I deleted some apps (from Settings -> General -> Usage.) Two of these apps are Spotify and LinkedIn.

[image]

Both Spotify and LinkedIn haven't deleted properly -- they're still listed on the home-screen, but won't open and have a white app icon. If I delete them they just re-appear on restart. After they're deleted the appstore only gives me the 'open'-option, I cannot reinstall them (nothing happens when pressing 'open'.)

I tried a hard reset, several restarts, and the apps both do not show up in Settings -> General -> Usage so I can't uninstall them from there. I have 4GB of free space on the phone so that shouldn't be an issue.

I'd love to have Spotify back. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it with 'Apple configurator 2' (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12). Connect iphone to macbook, launch Apple configurator 2, select device, click 'add -> apps', login with apple id, find spotify, click 'install', choose 'overwrite existing'.

Now on iPhone go back to the app-store and you can redownload it.